# Javascript - extracting a substring from complex alarms

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm currently trying to pull a specific piece of data out of automated alarms using javascript. The data can display in 3 possible ways depending on the device....

```
cWNotificationDescription = AP 'CC-PR555555' disassociated from Controller '111.11.111.11'.

OR.....

AP 'CC-PR555555' is being contained. This is due to rogue device spoofing or targeting AP 'CC-PR555555' BSSID on '802.11b/g' radio 

OR.....

'802.11a/n' interface of AP 'CC-PR555555' associated to controller 'CC-AA-5555 (111.11.111.11)' is down.
```

in any case, I'm looking to pull out `"CC-PR555555"`. Which might also display as `"PR55:55:55:55:55:55"` or `"devicename2"`, so the trick is pulling out whatever data is in that exact spot as it can be different lengths.

it always begins with AP and the data required is inside single quotes ' ' but in all alarms there are multiple data points included in single quotes, and in one of the alarms the desired data line is listed twice.

Any advice on how to extract this would be wonderful

Comment: Is it always wrapped by single quotes and following `AP`? By the way, I'm going to submit an edit for this removing `java` and `string` as tags as they are irrelevant.

Comment: Have you looked into regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use RegEx to find the values you are looking for, this simple regex will look for `AP '` and take everything before the next `'`

```js
let sampleInput = ["cWNotificationDescription = AP 'CC-PR555555' disassociated from Controller '111.11.111.11", "AP 'CC-PR555555' is being contained. This is due to rogue device spoofing or targeting AP 'CC-PR555555' BSSID on '802.11b/g' radio", "'802.11a/n' interface of AP 'CC-PR555555' associated to controller 'CC-AA-5555 (111.11.111.11)' is down."]

var r = /(?<=AP\s')CC-[^']*(?=')/;
for(let i = 0; i < sampleInput.length; i++){
  console.log("Found", r.exec(sampleInput[i])[0], "in", '"', sampleInput[i], '"');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm being throw head first into this for work and it's not something I have any experience with. been fun to learn though!

Comment: @SteveHall no problem, glad I could help.